# update query is not working in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

my query is:

```
$q = mysql_query("UPDATE `payment_details` SET `txnid`='$txnid',`amount`='$amount',`email`='$email',`firstname`='$firstname',`phone`='$phone',`productinfo`='$productinfo'  where `id`='$id' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

but is is working when i change id = "1";
please any one can help with this problem.

Comment: whehter `$id` variable getting value correctly?

Comment: yes sir my var id is in right place

Comment: $firstname =$_POST['firstname'];
 $email =$_POST['email'];
 $phone =$_POST['phone'];
 $productinfo =$_POST['productinfo'];
 $service_provider =$_POST['service_provider'];
 $amount =$_POST['amount'];
 $txnid =$_POST['txnid'];
 $productinfo =$_POST['productinfo'];
 $surl =$_POST['surl'];
 $furl =$_POST['furl'];   $q = mysql_query("UPDATE `payment_details` SET `txnid`='$txnid',`amount`='$amount',`email`='$email',`firstname`='$firstname',`phone`='$phone',`productinfo`='$productinfo'  where `id`='84' ") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: did you checked with `echo ` or `print_r` full query?

Comment: the above line is fill code

Comment: yes sir i have check it

Comment: Include quotes for string datatype values like below,
`UPDATE payment_details SET txnid='".$txnid."', amount='".$amount."', email='".$email."', firstname='".$f‌​irstname."', phone='".$ph‌​one."', productinfo='".$p‌​roductinfo."' where id='84'`

Comment: and $id is a number ? if there is, you should remove the quotes `where 'id'=$id ") or die`

Answer (score 1):

The function mysql_query is deprecated in php 5.5.
Also it`s not very cool to put values in database like that.

You can use [php PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and bind values

Use the bindParam and prepare in the PDO to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: and with this he'll solve his problem? Your answere should be a comment... VD!

Comment: He not going to have the problem if he use PDO.

Comment: i got this error when i tried to connect pdo Connected successfullyConnected successfullyAccess denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)$servername = "localhost";
$username = "grpictur_intel";
$password = "g%JxOFbbK4q=";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=grpictur_intel", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

Comment: Seems you connecting with user root somehow. There are few questions with this problem on stackoverflow. They have different suggestions you gotta try some.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if $id has a value or not with var_dump($id);

Second thing is that don't put your variables inside single quotes otherwise it will be considered as a string.You need to concatenate your variables or you can use curly braces which serve as a substitution for concatenation, they are quicker to type and code looks cleaner.

Try this:-

```
$q = mysql_query("UPDATE `payment_details` SET `txnid`='{$txnid}',`amount`='{$amount}',
`email`='{$email}',`firstname`='{$firstname}',`phone`='{$phone}',`productinfo`='{$productinfo}'  
     WHERE `id`='{$id}' ") OR die(mysql_error());
```

It will work fine.

Comment: $id =$_POST['id'];
when i check var_dump($id); its gives null my database is id ,firstname,amount,email,phone,productinfo,in

Comment: Are you sure you are posting the 'id' correctly. I mean do you getting any undefined index warning. Also check whether you are using post or get method to get id. If you are sending id in url then you have to use $_GET['id'] or $_REQUEST['id'].

Comment: sir i have check it gives null .

Comment: my form looks like: $id =$_POST['id'];

 $firstname =$_POST['firstname'];
 $email =$_POST['email'];
 $phone =$_POST['phone'];
 $productinfo =$_POST['productinfo'];
 $service_provider =$_POST['service_provider'];
 $amount =$_POST['amount'];
 $txnid =$_POST['txnid'];
 $productinfo =$_POST['productinfo'];
 $surl =$_POST['surl'];
 $furl =$_POST['furl'];

Comment: $q = mysql_query("UPDATE `payment_details` SET `txnid`='{$txnid}',`amount`='{$amount}',
`email`='{$email}',`firstname`='{$firstname}',`phone`='{$phone}',`productinfo`='{$productinfo}'  
     WHERE `id`='{$id}' ") OR die(mysql_error());

Comment: Use var_dump($_POST); to check data inside the post variable and see if there is index id or not.

Comment: can u tell me how do i pass id in $id =$_POST['id'];

Comment: sir it got this result array(0) { }

Comment: This means that your form data is not posted. Make sure you are posting the data on right url i.e. check url inside your form action attribute

Comment: how can i post form data sir.

Comment: Please share your html code so that i can figure out if there is some mistake.

Comment: form_process.php page

Comment: in payment form i retrive  value from my database table  payment_details and try to update in database table payment_details at the same time i want go the page to payment gate way if it fails its value will go to payment_details

Comment: these are the three files  to update the value if the payment is cancel

Comment: change isset($_POST['postForm']) to isset($_POST['submit']). And then use var_dump($_POST); to check if you are getting anything inside post.

Comment: hi sir ,the i have try yr query i got this resultarray(9) { ["txnid"]=> string(5) "29733" ["amount"]=> string(1) "1" ["firstname"]=> string(8) "Mithlesh" ["email"]=> string(22) "mithlesh@webrankey.com" ["phone"]=> string(8) "96789056" ["productinfo"]=> string(28) "ertyretewrtewrtewrtewrtewrte" ["surl"]=> string(49) "http://grpictures.in/intel/userportal/success.php" ["furl"]=> string(46) "http://grpictures.in/intel/userportal/fail.php" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" } BUT WHEN I TRIED I GOT NOT VALUE  $id =$_POST['id'];
 var_dump($id);

Comment: but used $id =$_POST['id'] var_dump($id); it gives null result

Comment: Your resultant array does not contains the index id that's why you are getting id as null. Send id from the form. Also check whether the id is retrived correctly from database.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the value of `$id` first and go from there.

```
var_dump($id);
```

If you get `null` or empty, there is your problem. If you get a non empty value, try to run the query in your mySQL client with the value that you got.

Also, it would help to see the error message that you are getting :)

Good luck.

Comment: $id =$_POST['id'];
when i check var_dump($id); its gives null my database is id ,firstname,amount,email,phone,productinfo,in

Comment: Well if your id gives you null. Then the problem is not database related. The problem lies in your post variable.